# How can I get exact solutions of this system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve system of equations
\begin{cases}
2 x^2-5 x y-y^2=y
   \left(\sqrt{x y-2
   y^2}+\sqrt{4 y^2-x
   y}\right),\\
   \sqrt{3
   y}+\sqrt{x^2+2 x}-x-x
   \sqrt{2+9 y^2}=0.
 \end{cases}
Where $x$, $y$ are two real numbers. I tried

```
Reduce[{2 x^2 - 5 x y - y^2 == 
  y (Sqrt[x y - 2 y^2] + Sqrt[4 y^2 - x y]), 
 Sqrt[3 y] + Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x] - x - x  Sqrt[2 + 9 y^2] == 0}, {x, 
  y}, Reals]
```

I can't get solutions for a long time. I know that, the given system of equations has two solutions $(0,0)$ and $(1,1/3)$. If I use `NSolve`

```
NSolve[{2 x^2 - 5 x y - y^2 == 
   y (Sqrt[x y - 2 y^2] + Sqrt[4 y^2 - x y]), 
  Sqrt[3 y] + Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x] - x - x Sqrt[2 + 9 y^2] == 0}, {x, 
  y}, Reals]
```

I only got

> {{y -> 0.333333, x -> 1.}, {y -> 0.333333, x -> 1.}}

Lost solution $(0,0)$.

How can I get exact solutions of this system of equations?

Comment: What you have above is invalid, generating a `Reduce::ivar` error.

Comment: Did you by any chance make a mistake in transcribing your code? `Reduce` should receive a single equation or a list of equations as its first argument, so you should wrap your equations in `{}`.

Comment: You could try using `GroebnerBasis[]` as a preprocessor before feeding to `Solve[]`.

Comment: Curiously, `NSolve` gives me an empty solution set, whereas `FindInstance` gives me only $\left( 0,0\right)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per @J.M. 's suggestion:

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[{Sqrt[3 y] + Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x] - x - 
     x Sqrt[2 + 9 y^2], 
    y (Sqrt[x y - 2 y^2] + Sqrt[4 y^2 - x y]) - (2 x^2 - 5 x y - 
       y^2)}, {x, y}];

eq = Thread[gb == ConstantArray[0, Length[gb]]];
Solve[eq, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 1/3}}

Comment: How about 
ClearAll
gb = GroebnerBasis[{Sqrt[x + 3] + Sqrt[x y + x + 3 y + 3] + x + 1 == 
     2 y + Sqrt[
      y + 1], (x - 3) (y + 1) == (y - 1) (x^2 - 2 x + 3) (Sqrt[
        x + 1] - 2)}, {x, y}];

eq = Thread[gb == ConstantArray[0, Length[gb]]];;
Solve[eq, {x, y}, Reals]

Comment: @toandhsp, one cannot just thoughtlessly apply `GroebnerBasis[]`; it is an aid, not a panacea. In that case, you pick out the entries that do not have a radical term, and feed those to `Solve[]`. In my trials, it was `gb[[1]] == 0` and `gb[[3]] == 0` that gave results.

Comment: In the case of the original set, picking out the first and fourth elements of `gb` netted sixteen real solutions, apart from the two displayed in this answer.